# Python infinite loop do something every x seconds without sleep

Tags: python

I'm developing something that needs an infinite loop and that can't use time.sleep or any other similar function to pause code execution and continue after x seconds. For this I am using a condition that does the interval calculation. However, the loop continues for milliseconds.

Example:

```
import datetime

def main():
    while True:
        period = datetime.datetime.now()
        
        # do something here
        
        if((period.second % 30) == 0):
            # every 30 seconds do something here 1 time, like saving in database
            print(period)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
2020-11-24 16:16:00.000767
2020-11-24 16:16:00.000767
2020-11-24 16:16:00.000767
...
2020-11-24 16:16:00.999772
2020-11-24 16:16:00.999772
```

I would like it to stop at the first or the last iteration, and after that the loop will continue.

Expected result:

```
# Program starts

2020-11-24 16:16:00.000767

# After 30 seconds

2020-11-24 16:46:00.000767

# And so on.
```

Comment: That's sort of what sleep is for. Can you explain more about why you can't use that?

Comment: Because am I using a library to connect to OPC DA, connecting with the server and using time.sleep to pause, after some time the server stops sending me data.

Comment: So sleep with a loop of shorter intervals. Without sleeping, you'll hog a CPU core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the last time you printed and print a new time only if it's more than one second after the last time.

```
lastTime = datetime.datetime.now()
while True:
    period = datetime.datetime.now()
     
    if period.second % 30 == 0 and (period - lastTime).total_seconds() >= 1:
        print(period)
        lastTime = period
```

Like Tigerhawk mentions in their comment, this isn't a great way of doing it though, because you're tying up a CPU core to do these iterations when it could be doing something else.

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of the *next* time you want to print the time.

```
def main():
    next_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)

    while True:
        period = datetime.datetime.now()
        
        # do something here
        
        if period >= next_time:
            # every 30 seconds do something here 1 time, like saving in database
            print(period)
            next_time += delta
            # Or, depending on how long the main body took
            # and when you want to do this again,
            # next_time = period + delta
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Timer Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) from the threading module:

In each iteration the function is called, it starts a new timer with the desired time interval to call itself and prints the current datetime. Thus the print is executed every x seconds.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

def print_periodicaly():
    Timer(30, print_periodicaly).start()
    print(datetime.now())

print_periodicaly()
```

Example Output:

```
2020-11-24 20:41:31.294023
2020-11-24 20:42:01.296045
2020-11-24 20:42:31.302457
2020-11-24 20:43:01.308902
2020-11-24 20:43:31.315336
2020-11-24 20:44:01.318833
...
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `period.second % 30` doesn't require "period.second" to be exactly 30, 60 etc, it can also be approximately, and thus the a number of outputs.

```
import datetime
from time import sleep

def main():
    while True:
        period = datetime.datetime.now()
        
        # do something here
        
        if((period.second % 30) == 0):
            # every 30 seconds do something here 1 time, like saving in database
            print(period)
            sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code above will sleep after the first approximation.